# Window Remote Desktop return to host shortcut

Tags: remote-desktop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut to minimize Remote Desktop](https://superuser.com/questions/207534/keyboard-shortcut-to-minimize-remote-desktop)

Is there any shortcut key to return to the host?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ctrl-Alt-Break swaps between fullscreen and non-fullscreen.

Comment: It does the trick but then I need to re-fullscreen it after that...

Comment: Press Ctrl-Alt-Break again.

Comment: Oh it works, that's great!!