# How to get Remote Desktop icon in taskbar

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

I'm using my work laptop to connect to my remote work desktop. When I do that, I get an icon of the remote session in the taskbar of my laptop, which means I can (for example) use Alt+Tab to go from Excel to the remote desktop.

However, when working on the (remote) desktop, I don't have an icon which allows me to use Alt+Tab to go back to my laptop. There is only the blue bar at the top of my screen which I can use to go back to my laptop, for which I need the mouse.

Any idea how to solve this? An alternative would be a suggestion on how to use keyboard shortcuts to go back to the laptop screen from the remote desktop screen.

Thanks

Comment: Why would there be an icon back to the desktop? Your PC isn't an open application from the remote desktop session

Comment: and also http://superuser.com/questions/209380/window-remote-desktop-return-to-host-shortcut

Answer (score 0):

If you want to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> back to your laptop, you need to tell RDC to apply Windows key combinations **On this computer**. The default is "when using full screen", which means that you can <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> *to* the RDC window, but can't <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of it.

[image: Picture of Remote Desktop Connection Local Resource Properties]

Note that changing this means you can no longer switch applications on the remote computer using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.