# How to restrict Windows RDP not to send certain keys to remote client?

Tags: windows, keyboard, remote-desktop

I'm occasionally working remotely (rather than on-site) and connect to my work place's desktop using Windows RDP. Both my host system and the remote machine are operating Windows 10 Pro systems. Now that I have an high-end audio setup to listen to headphones while working, I will need to play any music *on my local machine* to be able to listen to it properly. However, having entered full-screen RDP, obviously, my local computer's music program does no longer respond to the multimedia keys on my keyboard (the music, also obviously, keeps playing on my local machine), thus, I need to minimize the RDP connection every time I want to e.g. skip to the next track - which is just a waste of time. I searched the web, but couldn't find *a way to make Windows RDP not forward certain keys to the remote system*. Is there a chance achieve this whatsoever?

I'm not exactly sure whether this belongs to SuperUser (if not, please move it!) - but it certainly does not belong to Stack Overflow or ServerFault.

Comment: related https://superuser.com/q/207534/456981

Answer (score 3):

I think the only option you have is to disable Win+key and Alt+Tab combinations.
If that is acceptable for your workflow, then you can use this option. As it seems, it also disables multimedia keys. Furthermore you can use e.g. Autohotkey to extend the possibilities for disabled remote keys.
To set this option, click `Show Options` button on the bottom of the start RDP window.
Go to `Local resources` tab, then select `on this computer` dropdown option under Keyboard options.

Comment: This works, thanks. Let's see whether Alt+Tab is dispensable for the sake of having control over the music. Perhaps there's even software out there to map/route certain keys (in the remote machine) to another key combination, so I could possibly do CTRL+Tab or something. Let's see, and if not, perhaps a little C# does the trick.

Comment: @Johnny Alt+Tab maps to Alt+PgUp in RDP:  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/terminal-services-shortcut-keys