# Is there a modifier-key that will "break-out" windows shortcuts from an RDP session to the host when held?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Long story short, when I press  Ctrl+Win+[Left|Right] windows transitions from one virtual desktop to another. I have these key combos mapped to the left and right tilt functions on my mouse wheel.

I've also started to have to use RDP recently I prefer full-screen mode and this captures my windows hot-keys and sends them to the RDP'd computer, which is fine and makes sense. I want to keep this, as I'm actually using virtual desktops on the RDP machines.

I'm wondering -- is there a hotkey or modifier key I can hold that when using full-screen RDP will redirect windows hotkey combinations back to the host computer?

Comment: See if this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/207534/keyboard-shortcut-to-minimize-remote-desktop) helps.