# Is there a quick way to switch between a browser in the remote desktop, and a browser on my local machine?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, user-interface

I'm working alot in a remote desktop environment. However, I ifnd myself needing to switch back-&-forth too much between the remote desktop, and my PDF viewer on my local machine. And I can't use Alt-Tab or any keyboard shortcut(that I know of)

does anyone know of a way to get around that? Or how to easily switch beween the  remote desktop environment, and a locally running program?

many thanks

Comment: Buy a second monitor.

Comment: Citrix XenApp does this well. _Probably_ a little out of your scope however...

Comment: Have a close look at the above mentioned question, especially the [last (unaccepted?) answer](http://superuser.com/a/638855/50173)

Answer (score 1):

Print the pdf out.  Second monitor.  Alt-tab.  Use the windows+arrow keys to tile the windows evenly so you can see both at the same time.

Lots of potential answers for this, depending on your requirements.